# Request Method: POST Status Code: 401 Unauthorized While Clicking a Button to submit the form through Cypress Automation

Tags: cypress, http-status-code-401

I am trying to Click on a Button that submits the inputs during the automation in Cypress. While performing manual entry the data is submitted but while submitting through Cypress the input doesn't submit and leads to Status Code: 401 Unauthorized. [Cypress Test Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKBmw.png)

```
  context("Checking Add Importer Functionality", () => {
  it("submits the form accepting only the mandatory field", () => {
 
  cy.login(data.username, data.password);
  cy.get("[title=Static]").click().url().should("include", "/importer");
  cy.get(".css-1uccc91-singleValue")
    .contains("Importer")
    .type("importer {enter}");
  cy.get(".buttontext").contains("Add Importer").click();
  cy.get("[placeholder=Name]").should("be.visible").type("Ironman");
  cy.get("[name=nameNp]").should("be.visible").type("Ironman");
  cy.get("[name=eximCode]").clear().type("1234567891234");

  cy.get("[type=submit]").click();
```

[Used Preserve Once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBzmN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try & check by preserving your browser cookies
Ex:

```
beforeEach(() => {

        Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('<id>')
})
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies#Preserve-Once

Comment: Used Preserve Once But Didn't Work